# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when trying to installing npm globally

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, node.js

I am facing some trouble!

When running the following command
`subrara@subrara-desktop:~$ sudo npm install npm --global`

I am getting the following:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

I already have node and npm installed, now I want to update to the latest stable version of npm.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

A better way for me is to completely remove the `npm` and the `node` by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get update
which node
```

And reinstall using `nvm` the Node Version Management. To install `nvm` i follow this instruction. https://gist.github.com/d2s/372b5943bce17b964a79